# MS Teams Audio issues via Pixel 6

Tags: audio, google-pixel-6, microsoft-teams

In the last week I began running into an issue. Not sure if there was a system update (could have happened overnight).

**In short audio doesn't work in teams meetings until I clear the cache for the app.**

- Issue occurs with both wired and wireless headphones
- Audio will work via phone's built in speakers
- Once it is reset it will work for one meeting or a couple. I haven't figured out what triggers the issue
- Issue is limited to MSTeams, other applications (music/audible/youtube) work just fine.

So far I have tried:

- Restarts, which did nothing
- Removal/reinstall of the application, this worked similarly to clearing the cache, it helped but only temporarily

Teams vsn: 1416/1.1.1.2022363703

Android vsn: 12

Comment: If the issue is limited to Team and as if the workaround is to clear teams app cache this is clearly an app bug which should be reported to MS. Unfortunately MS has no way to create an bug report for an end user, so posting the bug in a MS forum would IMHO be better than posting it here.

Comment: @Robert Fair, I was hoping someone had a more permanent work around. Dealing with MS support is...unpleasant.